# Do you have a simple bzero example?

Tags: c, string.h

I need to implement `bzero`, I've read the manual, I saw a lot of posts about it on StackOverflow, but what I'm asking for is a simple example where you use bzero, I didn't find any simple example of using `bzero` instead of using it in server/client in C.

Ok so this is my memset:

```
void *my_memset(void *b, int c, size_t len)
{
    char *pb;
    unsigned char car;

    if (b == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    pb = b;
    car = (unsigned char)c;
    while (len--)
    {
        *pb++ = car;
    }
    return (b);
}

void ft_bzero(void *s, size_t  n)
{
     ft_memset(s, 0, n);
}
```

Looks fine?

Comment: Use `memset` instead of `bzero`.

Comment: Do you need to *use* or *implement* `bzero`?

Comment: i don't have the choice.

Comment: `void bzero(void *s, size_t n){ memset(s, 0, n);}`

Comment: `#define bzero(s, n) memset(s, 0, n)`

Comment: should i write : while (len > 0 && len--) ?

Comment: I was wrong.  Your code looks fine.

Comment: @user3540997 `len > 0` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

All `bzero()` does is memset everything to zero.

```
myStruct_t * foo = malloc (sizeof(myStruct_t));
bzero(foo, sizeof(myStruct_t));
// All bytes of foo are now 0
```

It's no different from calling

```
memset (foo, 0, sizeof(myStruct_t));
```

Under the hood, `bzero()` should match this implementation...

```
void bzero(void * s, size_t n)
{
  char * c = s; // Can't work with void *s directly.
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    c[i] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example:

```
char *test = malloc(256);

memset(test, 0, 256); // or bzero(test, 256);
```

This will set all elements of `test` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that memset returns a pointer when bzero don't. So if you want to reproduce the bzero(), this would probably be more like :

```
void    ft_bzero(void *s, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char *ptr;

    while (n-- > 0)
        *ptr++ = 0;
}
```

Comment: `ptr` is never intialized.  Also, this is made unnecessarily complex by using the bug-prone construct of cramming too much functionality into one line.  You gain **nothing** positive by writing code such as `*ptr++ = 0` instead of writing `*ptr = 0; ptr++;` over two lines - you're not saving lines in a textbook just to make each book cost a few pennies less and pay for the publisher's swimming pool.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example:

```
void    ft_bzero(void *s, size_t n)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        ((char *)s)[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
}
```